# How to indent additional line(s) in for/foreach/while/... header in ReSharper?

Tags: c#, resharper

Having Googled far and wide, couldn't find how to do that in ReSharper - I want to automatically add one tab to indent any **additional** line(s) in a `foreach`'s (for start... next is `for`, `while`, ...) header.

From this:

```
foreach(var stuff in _thingsFactory.GenerateThings()
    .Select(t => WrapThingWithStuff(t))
    .Where(stuff => stuff.AreRelevant)) {
    stuff.Foo();
}
```

To that:

```
foreach(var stuff in _thingsFactory.GenerateThings()
        .Select(t => WrapThingWithStuff(t))
        .Where(stuff => stuff.AreRelevant)) {
    stuff.Foo();
}
```

Does it even exist anywhere in ReSharper's settings?